# How do I use the external variables from external javascript file into index.pug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pug

Suppose, I have an external javascript file named `myscript.js`. It declares a variable named `headArr` which is an array.

```
 headArr = [`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`company`,`salary`];
```

In the `index.pug`, I have an include:

```
script
        include ../public/script/myscript.js
```

And I use an `each` iteration to read each member of the array.

```
ul
  each val in headArr
    li= val
```

It returns/shows error that `it can't read headArr.length return undefined`

Comment: How do you render your pug?

Comment: I use koa.js

router.get(`/`, async ctx => {
    await ctx.render(`index`)
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find the solution. Thank@ippi
In koa.js, you can use require only.

For my case:
In your script add

```
const head = [`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`company`,`salary`];

module.exports.head = head;
```

Then, index.js add

```
const myScript = require('./public/script/myscript');
```

Then render the page

```
router.get(`/`, async ctx => {
    await ctx.render(`index`,myScript)
});
```

Finally, add the Each iteration to your index.pug file

```
            tr
            each i in head
                th= i
```

Answer (score 0):

Then perhaps including your script server-side is an option for you?

```
// myscript.js
export const headArr = [`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`company`,`salary`];

// Where you do your rendering
import { headArr } from myscript.js
...
await ctx.render(index, { headArr });
```

Pug allows you to pass in variables as the second argument, which will be bound to window when rendered `{ test: "something" }` becomes `window.test`  . (ctx.render is just executing the compiledTemplate-function pug has generated);

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get(/, async ctx => 
    { await ctx.render ('index', { headArr: headArr} ) 
    });
```

In your myscript.js file, you can use this code while rendering index.pub. Because pug file takes object as a input and you need to pass headArr in that object.